# Insert coredata records from push notification when app is in background

Tags: core-data, swift3, push-notification

I need to insert records to the coredata for 2 entities from one push notification, when application is in background, but when I try to insert, it stops execution while fetching data from existing records and continues after another notification occurs or when user clicks on notification. 
I want data to be inserted when the user did not click on the push notification and when app is in background state.

Here is my code part to fetch record and to insert:

```
static func insertFromNotificationMessage(_ context: NSManagedObjectContext, message: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> myData{        
        var myData : myData?
        context.performAndWait {
            myData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(
                forEntityName: "myData", into: context) as? myData
            myData?.guid = message["id"] as? String
            myData?.title =  message["ttl"] as! String
            let anotherData = anotherData.getByUUID(context, UUID: message["id"] as! String) ?? anotherData.insertFromNotificationMessage(context, details: message)
            myData?.author = author

        do{
            try context.saveContextAndWait()
        }catch let error{
            print("Error\(error)")
        }
    }
    return myData!
}

static func getByUUID(_ context: NSManagedObjectContext, UUID : String)-> anotherData?{
        let fetchSingleRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "anotherData")
        fetchSingleRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "guid =[c] %@", UUID)
        do{
            let fetchedUser = try context.fetch(fetchSingleRequest) as! [anotherData]
            if fetchedUser.count > 0{
                return fetchedUser.first
            }
        }catch{
            print("Failed to fetch: \(error)")
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code better by adding 4 spaces before each 'static func', I tried to do it but the editor wouldn't let me save my changes.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the app delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    YOUR OBJECT CLASS.saveMessage(userInfo) // code to save into core data
    completionHandler(.NewData)
}
```

Here is my example function to save the data

```
static func saveMessage(userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> Message {

    let alertInfo = userInfo["aps"]?["alert"]!
    let title:String?
    let body:String?

    if let alertTitle = alertInfo!["title"] as? String{
        title = alertTitle
        body = alertInfo!["body"] as? String
    } else {
        title = userInfo["title"] as? String ?? "CUSTOM TITLE"
        body = alertInfo as? String
    }

    let message = Message(date: NSDate(), title: title!, message: body!, isReaded: false)
    DBUtil.saveContext()
    return message
}
```